# NHibernate CreateSqlQuery() result to an ObservableCollection

Tags: nhibernate, observablecollection

I've the following:

```
            using (ISession session = Config.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    // This is a System.Collections.ArrayList,contains all my records returned from the session
                    var list  = session.CreateSQLQuery(selectQuery).List(); 

                    // I want to put these records in an ObservableCollection of a specific Type
                    // Something like htis:
                    MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyType>(list);
                }
            }
```

This is not working and casting isn't an option here. Is there any way to put my retrurned list to the ObservableCollection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got my ObservableCollection filled by using the following:

```
   var query = session.CreateSQLQuery(selectQuery).AddEntity(typeof(MyType));
   myObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyType>(query.List<MyType>());
```

Answer (score 0):

The List() returns ArrayList. Each value in ArrayList has some value which is type of object.
It can not be converted into directly any specific class. so create a mapping file then only you can get list of your required object.
 [image]